# Can I use a SetTimer() API in a console C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, timer, console

I have a console application that is using a DLL file that uses a `SetTimer()` call to create a timer and fire a function within itself. The call is below:

```
SetTimer((HWND)NULL, 0, timer_num, (TIMERPROC)UnSyncMsgTimer)) == 0)
```

It is expecting to receive timer messages, but this never happens. I assume because mine is a console application and not a standard Windows GUI application (like where the DLL file was originally used). This stops a key part of the DLL files functionality from working.

My application needs to stay a console application, and I cannot change the DLL.

Is there a work around to make this work?

Comment: @Hans: JallenA1 said he can't change the DLL, so it is stuck using `SetTimer()`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [CreateTimerQueueTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HANDLE timer_handle_;
CreateTimerQueueTimer(&timer_handle_, NULL, TimerProc, user_object_ptr, 10, 0, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT);
//callback
void TimerProc(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    user_object* mgr = (user_object*) lpParameter;
    mgr->do();
    DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, timer_handle_, NULL);
    timer_handle_ = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Timers set using the `SetTimer` API require a Windows message processing function to be actively running, as that is where the time messages are sent.

If you need a timer thread then you could register a Window class and create a default window message pump (See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928(v=VS.85).aspx#creating_loop) for a short example), but a simpler process would probably be to just spin up a second thread to handle your timing events and send notifications.

Comment: You don't need a window class to create a message pump.  Just a simple loop that calls `Peek/GetMessage()`, `TranslateMessage()`, and `DispatchMessage()`.

Comment: This advice was very useful to me.  I created a simple thread, and the thread process calls `Sleep()` and then wakes up and performs its task.  Once you gave me the idea I got it done quickly; thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the following example which shows how to use WM_TIMER messages with a console app:

(Credit to the [Simple Samples](https://simplesamples.info/Windows/ConsoleTimer) site)

```
#define STRICT 1 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>

VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
  cout << "Time: " << dwTime << '\n';
  cout.flush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
      int Counter=0;
      MSG Msg;
      UINT TimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 500, &TimerProc);

      cout << "TimerId: " << TimerId << '\n';
      if (!TimerId)
        return 16;
      while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        ++Counter;
      if (Msg.message == WM_TIMER)
        cout << "Counter: " << Counter << "; timer message\n";
      else
        cout << "Counter: " << Counter << "; message: " << Msg.message << '\n';
      DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good example of creating and using a timer from a console application, however to make that example application actually do anything useful the timer handling (and windows message pumping) would need to go into a separate thread.

Comment: When will you exit the while loop? There is nothing posting a quit message up there, and there is no return, break or throw ...

Comment: @Chad: it does not necessarily need to be in a separate thread.  The loop could use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` or `GetQueueStatus()` to detect when messages are ready for processing, and can go off doing other things in the meantime.

Comment: True, but if you have experience with multithreaded programs already, then doing the timing in a thread is trivial compared to doing it with a WM_TIMER message and the appropriate constructs to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Waitable Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Timer Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? While it is possible to use `SetTimer` from a console app, these other facilities might be more appropriate for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Using Timer Queues
>
> Creates a timer-queue timer. This timer expires at the specified due
>   time, then after every specified period. When the timer expires, the
>   callback function is called.
>
> The following example creates a timer routine that will be executed by
>   a thread from a [timer queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686796(v=vs.85).aspx) after a 10 second delay. First, the
>   code uses the [`CreateEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create an event object
>   that is signaled when the timer-queue thread completes. Then it
>   creates a timer queue and a timer-queue timer, using the
>   [`CreateTimerQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682483(v=vs.85).aspx) and CreateTimerQueueTimer functions,
>   respectively. The code uses the [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) function to
>   determine when the timer routine has completed. Finally, the code
>   calls [`DeleteTimerQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682565(v=vs.85).aspx) to clean up.

For more information on the timer routine, see [`WaitOrTimerCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687066(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Example code from MSDN:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE gDoneEvent;

VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    if (lpParam == NULL)
    {
        printf("TimerRoutine lpParam is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // lpParam points to the argument; in this case it is an int

        printf("Timer routine called. Parameter is %d.\n", 
                *(int*)lpParam);
        if(TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            printf("The wait timed out.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The wait event was signaled.\n");
        }
    }

    SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123;

    // Use an event object to track the TimerRoutine execution
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the timer queue.
    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Set a timer to call the timer routine in 10 seconds.
    if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue, 
            (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerRoutine, &arg , 10000, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }

    // TODO: Do other useful work here 

    printf("Call timer routine in 10 seconds...\n");

    // Wait for the timer-queue thread to complete using an event 
    // object. The thread will signal the event at that time.

    if (WaitForSingleObject(gDoneEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(gDoneEvent);

    // Delete all timers in the timer queue.
    if (!DeleteTimerQueue(hTimerQueue))
        printf("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

**This is another example code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687008.aspx)**

**This is another example from [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/114859/Timer-in-console-application)**

```
#include <windows.h>
HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
unsigned long _stdcall Timer(void*)
{
    int nCount = 0;
    while(nCount < 10)
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, 5000);
    cout << "5 s\n";
    nCount++;
    }
    cout << "50 secs\n";
    return 0;
}
void main()
{
    DWORD tid;
    hTimer = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, Timer, NULL, 0, &tid);
    int t;
    while(cin >> t)
    {
        if(0==t)
            SetEvent(hTimer);
    }
    CloseHandle(hTimer);
}
```

Resource:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Very simple timer without Windows

```
MSG Msg;

UINT TimerId = (UINT)SetTimer(NULL, 0, 0, NULL); // 0 minute

while (TRUE)
{
    GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0);

    if (Msg.message == WM_TIMER)
    {
        KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);

        cout << "timer message\n";

        TimerId = (UINT)SetTimer(NULL, 0, 60000, NULL); // one minute.
    }

    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
```