# Timer working in Console Application

Tags: c++, timer, console

I'm trying to get a timer working in my c++ application.

I can define my timer:

```
#define  IDT_TIMER  WM_USER + 200 
UINT Timeval;
UINT TimerID = 1;
UINT TimerMS = 20;
```

Start Stop Timer methods:

```
UINT NAHDPbx::StartTimer (UINT TimerID)
    {

      UINT    TimerVal;
      TimerVal =  thewindow->SetTimer(TimerID, TimerMS, NULL);  // Starting the Timer
      return TimerVal;

    }// end StartTimer

BOOL NAHDPbx::StopTimer (UINT TimerID)
   {
          if (!KillTimer (TimerID))
          {
           return FALSE;
          }

         return TRUE;

   } // end StopTimer
```

And I start the timer like this:

```
Timeval=StartTimer(TimerID);
```

However in my code the timer tick never fires:

```
void NAHDPbx::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
    StopTimer(TimerID);

        //Do stuff

    StartTimer(TimerID);
}
```

Any examples of getting a timer to work? My end goal is to receive data via UDP, and need a way to send and receive at the same time.

Comment: What API are you using? I'm guessing you are using WIN32 API but you will need to show more codes like your main function before anyone  can figure out what mistake you made.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a SetTimer() API in a console c++ app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531650/can-i-use-a-settimer-api-in-a-console-c-app)

Answer (score 0):

If the console application exits, the timer handler will go out of scope and nothing will happen.