# How to set a timer in a console Win32 app?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a SetTimer() API in a console c++ app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531650/can-i-use-a-settimer-api-in-a-console-c-app)

I am looking to create a timer in c++ ,in a console win32 application .I google it and and find most results for SetTimer() ,but as example used for window control or others .

I need my timer to start a count ,right after the timer starts i call a function and after the timer ends ,i call an other function .I will be using threads .

I am a rookie in c++ ,so could this be done with SetTimer function ?

Thanks .

Comment: I didn't get your 'using threads' point. Would you like to run the timer in a thread?

Comment: carry on with reading about how to use the SetTimer() function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#creating_timer

Comment: Note that if you just wait to wait for a specified amount of time, you can use the simpler [Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not your way, `SetTimer` is based on Windows messages system and will not work in console app *just from box*. You will need to create message pumping loop manually and do several other staff that is hardly met with console app structure and control flow.

You could enjoy [Waitable Timers objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. They are designed specially to be used with threads as sync objects.

Usage example:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart=-100000000;

    // Create a waitable timer.
    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, "WaitableTimer");
    if (NULL == hTimer)
    {
        printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for 10 seconds...\n");

    // Set a timer to wait for 10 seconds.
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Wait for the timer.
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    else printf("Timer was signaled.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

See also nice article observing Windows timers: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial